# Tailwind Css custom color disappearing on build (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

My custom color "primary" is not working on the build mode and disappears. But on development mode it is present.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#C62C2C",
        secondary: "#6558f5",
        dark: "#000000",
      },
    },
    fontFamily: {
      body: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**Button Component**

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`rounded-lg ${props.className ? props.className : "1"} ${
        props.padding
      } text-sm text-white bg-${props.color}`}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

**Calling Button Component**

```
 <Button color="primary" padding="px-6 py-2"></Button>
```

Comment: Are all the other stylings present in your build version?

Answer (score 2):

If your color is passed down via `props.color` to be added to `bg-` to create `bg-primary`, then that's the problem.

The purge feature for Tailwind in production looks for the full text of classes and removes ones it doesn't find. Because the text is being assembled in the code, it's not finding `bg-primary` anywhere and not including that in the CSS it builds.

The easiest solution would probably be to pass the full class name instead of just the color part in `props.color` (i.e. `bg-primary` instead of just `primary`).

See the docs for more info: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html

Comment: Hi, What if we want the colour to be dynamic? Should we mention the required classes elsewhere tricking "purge" to ignore them?

Comment: EDIT to the above comment: It did work, not sure it's a good practice. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend passing the full class name - maybe as props.colorClass - or using a dictionary object (with color names as the properties and class names as the values so you can look up the appropriate values) instead of simply adding the class name elsewhere. (Both for clarity and ease of maintenance.)

Answer (score 0):

Easier answer is to add them to the `safelist` in your tailwind.config.ts:

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#safelisting-specific-classes